# FFMPEG and CPU utilization

Tags: ffmpeg, cpu

Is there a way to either set a maximum CPU utilization for ffmpeg, or
(preferably) to run ffmpeg at a lower priority so that it still runs
at 100% but gives up CPU to other processes as needed?

I am not sure if this is something I could set in ffmpeg itself or if
I need to run some sort of wrapper command or change a system setting.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are running this on Linux. A quick Google gave me this:
[**Changing Priority on Linux Processes**](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/)

> These guidelines are called niceness or nice value. The Linux niceness scale goes from -20 to 19. The lower the number the more priority that task gets. If the niceness value is high number like 19 the task will be set to the lowest priority and the CPU will process it whenever it gets a chance. The default nice value is zero.

Create new process with a specific priority:

```
nice -n [nice-value from -20 to 19] [command]
```

So, in your case:

```
nice -n 10 ffmpeg .....
```

Comment: No I am running it on Windows.